# Using input.source to capture input from a custom indicator (PineScript on Tradingview)

Tags: pine-script

[image]

I'm looking to use `input.source` to capture the signals from an indicator so I can backtest it's "bearish" or "bullish" text plots. I can't seem to figure out from the Tradingview manual how write my script, well the first line importing the inputs using `input.source`.

here's an example that's not working (see picture for what I'm trying to capture asa input)

```
// Create an input that sets Bear or Bull data the BSI calculates with
bsiData = input.source(Bullish, title="BSI Buy Signal")
```

I've tried variations on the below but each time I add the strategy to the indicator I receive an error. I'm sure it's something to do with my bring completely new to this. Any and all direction would be extremely appreciated. I've tried following the Tradingview manual which talks about a pull down and choosing the input from the indicator I want to capture from but I can't get that far. My error always says "Something went wrong. Please try again later."

```
// Create an input that sets Bear or Bull data the BSI calculates with
bsiData = input.source(Bullish, title="BSI Buy Signal")
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to do anything specific. Just have **ONE** `input.source` and the drop-down menu will automatically have source data from the other indicators.

[Here](https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/use-an-input-from-another-indicator-with-your-strategy-19584/) is the announcement for this feature where pretty much everything is explained.

> - They can be configured from the chart or from a script’s Settings/Inputs.
> - Only one external input can be used at a time by the strategy.
> - The strategy must contain only one input() call using the    input.source type.
> - The external input used must be a plot from a study script.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

src = input.source(close, "Source")
plot(src)
```

[image]

Comment: Vitruvius you are a godsend, I can't thank you enough. I know this is super simple but I just couldn't get this one piece before manipulating the input for backtesting. Thanks for taking the time on this one! I'd upvote it if I could but my account is too new I guess.